# Why Material Design Top App Bar has little gap from the top?

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am using [Material Design](https://material.io/develop/web/components/top-app-bar/) Top App Bar. I noticed it has a little gap and I inspected the elements I can't seem to see if it has a margin at the top.

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Twitter | Favorites</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/twitter-favorites.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="top-bar" class="mdc-top-app-bar">
        <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
            <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
                <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon--unbounded">
                    menu
                </button>
                <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Tweets</span>
            </section>
            <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-end">
                <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item--unbounded"
                    aria-label="Download">file_download</button>
                <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item--unbounded"
                    aria-label="Print this page">print</button>
                <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item--unbounded"
                    aria-label="Bookmark this page">bookmark</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="tweets">
        <h1>Hello Tweets</h1>
    </section>
    <script src="/js/twitterFavorites.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

SASS / Styling:

```
@import "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";
@import "@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button";

$mdc-theme-primary: #fcb8ab;
$mdc-theme-secondary: #feeae6;
$mdc-theme-on-primary: #442b2d;
$mdc-theme-on-secondary: #442b2d;

body {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Is this expected to have a gap on the top?

Comment: I guess so, but margin: 0 should have fixed it. I believe something else is adding it.

Comment: @10101010 I did try putting 0 margin of the top bar (which is a header element) it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a custom Id to the header..

```
id="top-bar"
```

Does this top-bar have special CSS?
Try removing it.

Also, Press F12 and hover over the item and click on it. Margin or padding is shown with a different color. You can check if the element generated the padding or margin at the top. 
https://hackernoon.com/til-using-box-model-of-chrome-dev-tools-c1cdd4081693

Maybe it's another element generating the padding/margin.